# Anchor click shows div and scrolls to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of links on my page and each link has a related div (a description to that item) that is hidden. I want to give the related div a slideDown when the anchor is clicked but I also want the window to scroll to the beginning of that div. How can I achieve this?

```
<ul>
<li>Link 1</li>
<li>Link 2</li>
</ul>

<div id="link1">
</div>

<div id="link2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the anchor that u say?

Here u must repair your code

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:scrollElement('#link1');return false;">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:scrollElement('#link2');return false;">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="subpage" id="link1">
</div>

<div class="subpage" id="link2">
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function scrollElement(target)
{
     $(".subpage").hide();
     $(target).slideDown('slow');
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top }, 1000);
}
```